# URI not Recognized after import to Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I imported an app into Android Studio and I get this error.

"URI not Recognized".  It gives me the the  menu path to load the URI, but even after I do, and clean and rebuild...nothing.  When I try to load the link, it asks for a path.  I attempted to use the path to my source, but it didn't fix anything either.

Here are the screenshots.

[image: This is the line that gets the error]

[image: This shows no resources]

Answer (score 0):

To convert the project for android studio visit the link
[Convert project to android studio](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem after a hard drive(C:/) crashed and I had to back up from a flash drive.  After I copied the files from the flash drive to my newly installed hard drive, Android Studio could open the package, but not build/run the app. It could only build and run it from the flash drive(E:/).

I had embedded the file inside another copy of the same file. When I opened the file in Android Studio the green Android Studio icon would show up beside the file like it was the right one! However I had to again click that file to see that my file was actually embedded inside.  Another Android Studio icon was beside the embedded one too.

By finding this embedded file, and selecting it, I could open the package in Android Studio, of course after the Gradle build and syncing.

It may be that the uri problem has to do with getting the right path to the file for A-Studio to find.  On one other occasion A-Studio indicated it had found "frame works",  I clicked the window selector and chose "directory".  That cleared up the uri problem but it still couldn't open right without going through the right file path.